# Pymongo - aggregating from two databases

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

Noob here. I need to get a report that is an aggregate of **two collections from two databases**. Tried to wrap my head around the problem but failed. The examples I have found are for aggregating two collections from the same database.

**Collection 1**

SweetsResults = client.ItemsDB.sweets

Collection sweets : _id, type, color

**Collection2**

SearchesResults = client.LogsDB.searches

Collection searches : _id, timestamp, type, color

The report I need will list all the sweets from the type “candy” with all the listed colors in the sweets collection, and for each line, the number (count) of searches for any available combination of “candy”+color.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below script in mongo shell.

Get the distinct color for each type followed by count for each type and color combination.

```
var itemsdb = db.getSiblingDB('ItemsDB');
var logsdb = db.getSiblingDB('LogsDB');

var docs = [];
itemsdb.getCollection("sweets").aggregate([
    {$match:{"type":"candy"}},
    {$group: {_id:{type:"$type", color:"$color"}},
    {$project: {_id:0, type:"$_id.type", color:"$_id.color"}}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    doc.count = logsdb.getCollection("searches").count({ "type":"candy","color":doc.color});
    docs.push(doc)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as in [@Veeram answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48289505/6689249) but with python:

```
uri = 'mongodb://localhost'
client = MongoClient(uri)
items_db = client.get_database('ItemsDB')
logs_db = client.get_database('LogsDB')

docs = []
aggr = items_db.get_collection('sweets').aggregate([
    {'$match': {"type": "candy"}},
    {'$group': {'_id': {'type': "$type", 'color': "$color"}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'type': "$_id.type", 'color': "$_id.color"}},
])
for doc in aggr:
    doc['count'] = logs_db.get_collection("searches").count({"type": "candy", "color": doc['color']})
    docs.append(doc)
```